# How to modify "save" action on Interactive Grid

Tags: button, grid, action, apex, interactive

Is there a way to modify the logic of the "save" action of the SAVE button on an Interactive Grid ?

I want to add some logic before the save action is triggered.

I tried adding a new SAVE custom button that do the job but I want to reuse the current SAVE button instead of creating a new one.

This is the logic I'm using to create my new button:

```
function(config) {
  var $ = apex.jQuery,
      toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar(),
      toolbarGroup = toolbarData.toolbarFind("actions2"); // this is the group with the actions menu

  // add a custom save button after the actions menu
  toolbarGroup.controls.push( {
      type: "BUTTON",
      action: "custom-save",
      iconBeforeLabel: true,
      hot: true
  });
  config.toolbarData = toolbarData;

  config.initActions = function( actions ) {

    actions.add( {
        name: "custom-save",
        label: "Save",
        action: function(event, focusElement) {
          customSaveAction();  
        }
    } );

    actions.hide("save");
}
  return config;
}
```